# AngularJS - How can I change just one routeParam and redirect?

Tags: routes, angularjs

I've got a route that looks like this:

```
/Route/:Param1/:Param2/:Param3
```

In my controller, I'd like to modify one of those routes and then redirect to that. So if my route is this:

```
/Breakfast/:Eggs/:Bacon/:Cereal
```

I'd like to easily route to:

```
/Breakfast/:Eggs/:Waffles/:Cereal
```

without manually rebuilding the route. Is there a way that I can just do something like this:

```
$routeParams.Param2 = "Waffles";
$location.path($route);
```

Comment: AFAIK, core AngularJS does not have this functionality. Though, you can write simple regexp with callback that will replace :placeholders with values, feed result to $location.path(), and wrap all of this into service.

Also, you can try [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) -- a bit of overkill for your task, but it includes lots of interesting things inside. But will require you to change your code substantially.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, following up my comment above, here is working sample: http://jsbin.com/owiful/1/edit. Service code needs some checks, of course, but it works as it is now.